# Tweets extraction from mongodb using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

Using node.js i am able to save the tweets in mongoDB as well as display in the console. But unable to send the tweets from MongoDB to the browser(or localhost). Can anyone please guide me
        The below code fetches the tweets from twitter and

```js
var express = require('express'),
twitter = require('ntwitter');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('tweakdb', ['tweakdb']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express.createServer();


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var twit = new twitter({
consumer_key: '',
consumer_secret: '',
access_token_key: '',
access_token_secret: ''
});


twit.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['family', 'friends','teacher'] }, function(stream) {
stream.on('data', function (data) {

   console.log(data.user.screen_name + ': ' + data.text);
    db.tweakdb.findAndModify({
      query: {'id': 'data.id'},
        update: { $set: data},
        upsert: true,
        new: true
    }) 
 

var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var app = connect();
app.use(serveStatic('public'));
app.listen(3000);

});
```

This is the js script which i have written in HTML to display tweets in browser but its not getting displayed. How do i proceed further ? Can anyone help

```html
<script type = "text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:1337');
  var ul = document.getElementById("tweets");
  socket.on('tweet', function(tweet)
  {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML="<strong>" +tweet.user.screen-name+ ":</strong>" +tweet.text;
     ul.insertBefore(li,ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[0]);  
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give us some code snippets of what has been attempted?

Comment: can you please edit your question to show us saved collection prototype?

Comment: I have updated my code snippets. Please check and guide me with the next step. It would me a great help.

Comment: but you had written only code of insertion. Which field you want to search with. is there relation between your tweets and other document. and if yes which filed?

Comment: You're missing the socket.io logic on the server side. Here's an example using [Express and Socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-the-express-framework).